# Angular Scope variable appends result from $http to data variable instead of overwriting it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following Angular function that automatically refreshes the data in the view via an `$http` call invoked on an `$interval`

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

    $scope.data

    $scope.LoadData = function() {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'Home/DataRefresh',
            params:{'_': +new Date() }
        }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;


  }, function error(errResponse) {
            alert("data " + errResponse.data + " status " + errResponse.status + " headers " + errResponse.headers + "config " + errResponse.config + " statusText " + errResponse + " xhrStat " + errResponse.xhrStatus);
        });
    };  

    // Initial data load
    $scope.LoadData();
    // Refresh data on an interval
    $interval($scope.LoadData, 10000);
});
```

It is invoked and the data is displayed with the following HTML

```
    <main class="container" role="main" ng-controller="processModel">

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <table>
                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">

                        <td>{{item.info}}</td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </main>
```

The issue that I'm having is that when Home/DataRefresh is called every 10 seconds, the View just adds the new (and duplicate) items the end of the existing table instead of overwriting it. So it's either appending the new values to `$scope.data` or it's not automatically redoing the table built by `ng-repeat`.

What can I do to get it to just overwrite the contents of the table with the new data it gets from Home/DataRefresh ?

Comment: Can you have the results of the initial call and subsequent call results pasted in here? We're assuming the data is the same but it may not be.

Comment: Use the developer console to find what data is coming from the server.

Comment: Try: $scope.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));`. Also, the initialization of `$scope.data` should be something like: `$scope.data = {};`.

Comment: The problem is likely caused by server side code. There is no reason that AngularJS would do what you describe.

Comment: @georgeawg you were correct, it was an issue with the data connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the server side code, it wasn't clearing cache when it made a new Get call to the database. The angular was working fine.